# Blur function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use blur function, however, its not working. I want to hide the div if user clicks outside.

```
<div id="container">
Links
</div>

$(document.body).on('blur', '[id="container"]' ,function(){
$("#container").hide();
});
```

What is the correct way ?

Comment: What's the `id="container"`? And there's nothing called `document.body` here.

Comment: Just a div with links inside. Not an input.

Comment: **1.** `document.body` should be `document`. **2.** `[id="container"]` should be `#container`. **3.** The `<div />` doesn't have a `blur` event. So use `click` event instead of `blur`.

Comment: 1- Why ? 2- No, since its dynamically added, i need to use this to make it work. 3- ok.

Comment: **1.** No, there's no selector like that. **2.** Just for a better selector. Makes no difference. You are already delegating by using `.on` on `document`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue:

1. `document.body` should be `document`.
2. `[id="container"]` should be `#container`. Better selector.
3. The `<div />` doesn't have a `blur` event. So use `click` event instead of `blur`.

The `tabindex` way:

Giving the attribute `tabindex` enables the element to have `blur` and `focus` events. Now giving `blur` on it will work.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).on('blur', '#container' ,function(){
  $("#container").hide();
});
```

```css
#container {height: 100px; background: #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" tabindex="1">Click Me and Outside Me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What's tabindex for ?

Comment: I added this: *Giving the attribute `tabindex` enables the element to have `blur` and `focus` events. Now giving `blur` on it will work.*